# save for two table - doctrine and symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

i have two table:

```
News:
id
title
body
```

and

```
NewsCopy:
id
title
body
```

if i add new News i would like also add this same all data for table NewsCopy?

```
class News extends BaseNews
{
    public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
    {

      return parent::save($conn);
    }
}
```

how can i make this simply?

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of this Copy table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one possible way is to hook up into the Doctrine saving mechanism:

```
class News{
    //..other declarations//

    //executed after Save
    public function postSave(){
        $newsCopy = new NewsCopy(); 
        //set the parameters manually
        $newsCopy->id = $this->id;
        $newsCopy->title = $this->title;
        $newsCopy->body = $this->body;

        //OR, even better, create a "cast constructor" the same idea
        //$newsCopy = new NewsCopy($this);

        $newsCopy->save();
    }
}
```

See ["Event Listeners"](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/en#event-listeners) chapter for more detailed explanation

Comment: That code will trigger exceptions when updating an existing News though.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the toArray() method of the existing and populated "News" record object and populate a separate CopyNews object. With the now newly configured object you can do the save with.

I assume doctrine 1.2 - and I do not have a testing environment - so no code :).

You could probably also play with the clone() method and set a new table name ...

All untested - sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use triggers

Comment: how can i make with doctrine?